Unable to upsert data to salesforce from node js
I am trying to upsert records to Case object from node js app using jsforce.I am providing externalId field also as showing below.
const upsertTest = async () => {
        const sfconn = await createSalesForceConnection(options);        
        const caseData = {
            "test_Id__c": "1234",
            "Account": {
              "type": "Account",
              "Grc_AccountId__c": "123456"
            }
          };
          sfconn.sobject('Case').upsert(caseData, 'test_Id__c', (err, ret) => {
            if (err) {
                 return console.error(err); }
            console.log('Upserted Successfully:', ret);
          });   
}

This is failing with error :INVALID_FIELD: More than 1 field provided in an external foreign key reference in entity: Account
How to resolve this issue.
I have tried giving the case data as below, which is succeeding.
const caseData = {
            "test_Id__c": "1234",
            "Account": {
              "Grc_AccountId__c": "123456"
            }
          };

What is the reason the code is not  working with
"type":"Account"


I got a solution to this issue. Jsforce does not accept specifying the type of the object as "type":"Object_Name".   Even without specifying the type the transaction will succeed.
